# Rotate text under image and pin to the left of the image

Tags: css

I need to rotate some text under an image and place it to the left of the image and vertically centre it. Im using this with a CMS so the exact height and width of the image will vary. I also need to centre the image on the page.

This is what I have:
[image]

And this is what im trying to achieve: 
[image]

Here is my fiddle, but I havnt got very far with it: http://jsfiddle.net/FgA8x/5/

This is the rough structure of the html, but this could be changed if needs be:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/young-footballer-1642893.jpg" width="150px" height="250px" />
    <p>This is some caption text</p>
</div>    

<div>
    <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/young-footballer-1642893.jpg" width="300px" height="250px" />
    <p>This is some caption text</p>
</div>    

<div>
    <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/young-footballer-1642893.jpg" width="500px" height="250px" />
    <p>This is some caption text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to get the spacing right, but this as a general idea of how to get the caption to line up on the left using `display: inline` on the container and `float: left` on the caption text. Heres a fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/FgA8x/8/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesnt seem to worth without the paragraphs line height being set. As im working with a CMS the actual height of the images will vary.